# Reference a field in word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a table at the top of a document with a cell for Project Name and I want to mirror this at the bottom of the document to say whatever the top ones says as there is another part saying Project Name and I don't want to have to type it out everytime as I do it multiple times daily.

Same as if I was in Excel and I wanted A19 to equal A1.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

The first is via a Bookmark and Cross-reference.

- select the text you are wanting to make common
- click the `Insert` tab and select `Bookmark`
- name the bookmark, "ProjName" or something memorable, and click the `Add` button
- go to your footer, and again in the `Insert` tab select `Cross Reference
- in the new dialog you should be able to change the first drop down to `Bookmarks` and see your newly created bookmark, clicking `Insert` in this dialog should copy the contents of the bookmark

This is the way you are meant to do it but the bookmark is a fragile thing and prone to requiring recreation if you delete a character from the start or end of the bookmark.

My preferred method is now to use document styles and fields, which are much easier to apply,  manage and generally work with.  The process is similar to bookmarking but also allows you extra flexibility such as per-page titles that are dependant on headers and the like, I have a generic header that gets a single document title from the first page and copies the current page heading  to the header as well.

- select the text you want to appear in your footer
- right click the text, go to `Styles` and select to add a new style
- name the style as something you'll not be tempted to apply to any other text in the document, it is important that you only use this style on this piece of text
- in the footer again, under the `Insert` menu select `Field`
- scroll down to create a `Styleref` field, and select the name of the style you just created
- clicking `Insert` should insert your text

I find the styleref method to be more versatile and durable, and takes less time to fix when formatting or text changes but how you go about it is your choice.

Comment: Perfecto! Cheers.

Comment: The field doesn't update automatically though when using a reference. How can this reference show the original text without me having to right-click and select "update field"?

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select everything in your document and then <kbd>F9</kbd> to update field - that will update all fields in your entire document.

Also depending on your settings when you go to print, the print preview will trigger that update too.