# Can I create a custom Field Code in Word 2010 or use a Macro?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word 2010 and would like to use a "field code" in a contract so that I only have to type the Company's name in once and then have it update the rest of the document.  Do I do this in Quick Parts or maybe use a macro instead?

Comment: You can also use bookmarks as I just discovered: http://superuser.com/questions/433874/reference-a-field-in-word-2010

Answer (score 4):

Insert a "DocProperty" type field code. If you have the "Company" document property filled with the company name then these field codes will be populate with this company name.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new Property Field (File->Info->Advanced Properties [under 'Properties'])

  - Custom Tab
  - Name: "Example Field"
  - Type: Text
  - Value: "1.0"
  - Click 'Add', then 'OK'
  - This adds it to the displayed 'Properties' listing
  - If you ever want to revise or change it, come back to this listing and select it, update the displayed value in 'Value' and press the new 'Modify' button
- Insert the new field into use in document

  - From document you want to insert this into (Insert->Text->Quick Parts->Field)
  - Category: Document Information
  - Field name: DocProperty
  - Property: 'Example Field'

Whenever update of the value is needed use the process listed above to re-access the property. Then press Ctrl+A, then F9 and select ‘All’ for update to complete. This does not apply to Headers & Footers, these need manual updates (R.C.->Update Field), not sure why but quite easy to do!