# Creating substitution definitions in word

Tags: microsoft-word

One of the amazing things about latex is I could create defitions in a separate source .tex file and inport those defintions into a working target file.  For instance, I could define a term like Plaintiff Name as /PN in a source file and then instead of typing the name each time, just use /PN.  Because it is in a source file, I could also load the defs into all target files related to the same matter.  This also saves huge amounts of time reusing a form for another client since I only have to redefine /PN and print.

How do I do this in word?  The best work around I have come up with uses the mail merge dialog box, but it's really clunky.  There must be a way using fields to pull directly from an Excel spreadsheet, or even better to create a list of defined field terms in a source word doc.

Comment: If you write your documents exactly as at present, you can do a global search and replace before printing. You will want to set the options for match case and find whole words only.

Comment: Thanks, that is an idea, but very clunky because once the substitution is made, it is hard to back track.  I really need it to be an updateable field :)

Comment: @ custom dictonary.  I'm not exactly sure how it solves my problem to create a custom dictonary?

Comment: Approximately how many definitions do you need to store?

Comment: In Word, {fields} do exactly that.  The explanation in the Word help is very thorough.

Comment: At bibadia, about 20.  I am having some luck with using the LINK field command with excell, but then it automatically changes my relative paths to absolute paths.  Word is just infuriating.

Comment: @fixer1234, what do you mean.  I know about fields, but not how to utilize them specifically in this context.

Comment: It's been years since I used them, but I used them in that way.  My recollection is that I defined the fields on one page of the document and then just inserted a field referencing it where I needed it.  I learned everything I needed to know from the Word help.  BTW, there are many different types of fields; they are a pretty powerful tool.

Comment: I dont know fixer1234, im a pretty high-level user of fields and i've been at this over 8 hours.  If you had an example from your doc of how you define a field id be super appreciative :). This should be so easy, but word turns it into a freaking disaster.

Comment: O.k.  I finally got it.  You have to use "set" and "ref" field codes to create and retrieve bookmarks.  and you can call up a madter index file with relative paths using the includetext field.  That was brutal.

Comment: The second question I had was whether changes to the defined texts should result in changes to all existing documents, or whether each document should be independent, but allow the text to change throughout the document with a single definition change in the document. In the first case, INCLUDETEXT will work. You may be able to simplify what you have: in the included file, type the text you want to include, select that text and insert Bookmark instead of using SET. Use { INCLUDETEXT "the file path name" "the bookmark name" }. No REFs. You can create an Autocorrect to insert each definition.

Comment: I'm not sure if these are close enough for one to be closed as a duplicate, but I think this is what you're looking for: http://superuser.com/questions/446776/can-i-create-a-custom-field-code-in-word-2010-or-use-a-macro?rq=1